# Merge and join multiple excel files in R

Tags: r

I have 3 excel files (.xlsx) that I want to merge into one dataframe. Each file is for one clinic site- columns signify week of clinic activity (these weeks are standardized). However, sites started running at different weeks, so not all sites have data for each week. The rows are diagnoses- each site has a core group of the same diagnoses, but some sites have additional ones.

I want to get one data frame so I can analyze the total number of diagnoses per week across all sites.

site1:

```
diagnosis     wk2   wk3   wk 4
condition1    1     4     10
condition2          10    4
```

site2:

```
diagnosis     wk1   wk2   wk 3  wk4
condition1    6           4     7
condition2          8     9
```

site3:

```
diagnosis       wk1   wk2   wk 3  wk4
condition1      6           4     7
condition2      8     9
condition3      3     11    11    12
```

Desired dataframe:

```
diagnosis       wk1   wk2   wk 3  wk4
condition1      12    1     12    24
condition2      8     17    19    4
condition3      3     11    11    12
```

I have tried various combinations of merge, lapply, rbind, join, etc. but nothing is giving me the result I want.

The closest I got was this code:

```
files <- list.files(path ="data", pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names= T) %>%
  lapply(read_xlsx, sheet =1) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

This worked in that it merged all the columns across, but repeats the rows for each site even when the diagnoses are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need a `sum` of all values in wk1 through wk4 for every condition, we may want to use `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)

files <- list.files(path ="data", pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names= T) %>%
  lapply(read_xlsx, sheet =1) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  group_by(diagnosis) %>%
  summarise(across(wk1:wk4, ~sum(na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use {powerjoin}:

```r
site_1 <- tibble::tribble(
    ~diagnosis, ~wk2, ~wk3, ~wk4,
  "condition1",    1,    4,   10,
  "condition2",    0,   10,    4,
)

site_2 <- tibble::tribble(
    ~diagnosis, ~wk1, ~wk2, ~wk3, ~wk4,
  "condition1",    6,    0,    4,    7,
  "condition2",    0,    8,    9,    0,
)

site_3 <- tibble::tribble(
    ~diagnosis,  ~wk1, ~wk2, ~wk3, ~wk4,
  "condition1",    6,    0,    4,    7,
  "condition2",    8,    9,    0,    0,
  "condition3",    3,   11,   11,   12,
)

powerjoin::power_full_join(
  list(site_1, site_2, site_3),
  by = "diagnosis",
  conflict = rw ~sum(.x, .y, na.rm = TRUE)
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   diagnosis    wk1   wk2   wk3   wk4
#>   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 condition1    12     1    12    24
#> 2 condition2     8    17    19     4
#> 3 condition3     3    11    11    12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>